# infile does not read file contents

Tags: c++, file-io

im trying to read in the file Rooms.txt:

```
Room ID: 1.
Room Name: Beach East.
Room Exits: 2, 3.

Room ID: 2. 
Room Name: Beach West.
Room Exits: 1.

Room ID: 3.
Room Name: Forest.
Room Exits: 1,4.

Room ID: 4.
Room Name: Cave.
Room Exits: 3.
```

But im not getting the correct input. Room name is -8987678678.
I cant figure out why im getting garbage...
This is the function ive written to read the text file, Can anyone see a problem:

```
void Rooms :: loadRooms()
 {
    string fileName = "Rooms\\Rooms.txt";
    ifstream infile(fileName);
    string garbage;
    int loadID;
    string loadName;
    string loadExits;
    //while( )
    //{
        infile >>garbage; 
        infile >>loadID ;
        infile >>garbage; 
        infile >>garbage;
        infile >> loadName;
        infile >> garbage;
        infile >>garbage; 
        infile >>loadExits;
        infile >>garbage;
        cout << "Room ID: \t\t"<< loadID << "\n";
        cout << "Room Name: \t\t"<< loadName << "\n";
        cout << "Room Exits: \t\t" << loadExits<<"\n";
    //}

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`operator>>` for an std::string (as in `infile >> garbage;`) reads a single, white-space delimited word, so your first `infile >> garbage;` reads (and sort of discards) `Room` from the input. Then `infile >> LoadId` attempts to read `ID:` from the input and put it into `LoadId`. Since `ID:` isn't an integer, that conversion fails.

That sets the `fail` bit for the stream so all further attempts at reading from the stream fail immediately.

You probably want to write a small routine to read (and possibly verify) a label and a value associated with that label, then use it to read the data, so the code would look something like:

```
loadID = getvalue(infile, "Room ID");
loadName = getvalue(infile, "Room Name");
loadExits = getvalue(infile, "Room Exits");
```

In this case, `getvalue` would be something like:

```
std::string getvalue(std::istream &infile, std::string const &label) { 
    std::string input_label;

    std::getline(infile, input_label, ':');
    if (input_label != label) {
        // handle the error -- the label in file didn't match what we expected
    }
    std::string ret;
    std::getline(infile, ret);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I had no check to see if the file was actually opened so i tested and realized that rooms.txt was actually rooms.txt.txt.  So morale of teh story is make sure to have a check for the file name.

Comment: @user2355394: That would probably help too.